# How to plot Metrics of Rest API response body size written in Dropwizard Java Application

Tags: dropwizard, codahale-metrics

I have a Java application written in dropwizard and pushing timed metrics via @Timed annotation. I also want to plot the response body size graph (total size of API response, P99 and P50 response size) graph. Is there any way we can plot this?

Have gone through Dropwizard doc but not able to find any capability right now.